# Cypress Test Runner unexpectedly exited via a exit event with signal SIGSEGV in circleCI

Tags: javascript, cypress, circleci

I am stuck in this problem. I am running cypress tests. When I run locally, it runs smoothly. when I run in circleCI, it throws error after some execution.
Here is what i am getting:

```
[334:1020/170552.614728:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[334:1020/170552.616006:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[334:1020/170552.616185:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[521:1020/170552.652819:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
```

**Current behavior:**
When I run my specs headless on the circleCI, Cypress closed unexpectedly with a socket error.

**Error message**:

> The Test Runner unexpectedly exited via a exit event with signal
> SIGSEGV
>
> Please search Cypress documentation for possible solutions:
>
> https://on.cypress.io
>
> ---
>
> **Platform:** linux (Debian - 10.5)
> **Cypress Version:** 8.6.0

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself, with version 8.6.0. It runs smoothly locally and throws this error in CircleCI.

Comment: @jtiscione Issue resolved by reverting back cypress version to 7.6.0.

Comment: Actually my CircleCI process was failing because some of my API calls still needed updating from Cyress 6. Now that they're fixed, the tests pass, but this message still appears in the output.

Comment: I also opened the issue on github, you may follow the progress there https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/18569

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue resolved by reverting back cypress version to 7.6.0.

Comment: Finally, After 4 hours of struggle to run cypress came to an end. Downgraded version `8.7.0` -> `7.6.0`. +1

Comment: Downgrading Cypress or any dependency is bad practice. There is likely deprecated or buggy code in either your Cypress tests or your dependencies which causes the shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on within our Azure builds as well.  We only recently migrated from Cypress 8.4.0.  Going back to that has solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is an issue with newer labels

Answer (score 1):

downgrade the cypress by running `npm install cypress@7.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade of cypress to 8.3.0 worked for me to solve that, you dont need to go to previous versions.

```
npm install cypress@8.3.0
```

Comment: I hate that downgrading is the only solution but that's what worked for me. Ubuntu 20.* here.

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEGV means a segmentation fault error. Read all about it [here](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/how-to-debug-node-segfaults/).

> "In practice, a segfault occurs when your program breaks some
> fundamental rule set by the operating system. In that case, the
> operating system sends your process a signal (SIGSEGV on Mac & Linux,
> STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION on Windows), and typically the process shuts
> down immediately."

This blog post also goes into detail about how this can occur, even if you don't directly interact with the operating system (since we're writing JavaScript). Please read it on the original author's site for context.

But in short - you are likely encountering this error because

a. you upgraded Cypress while on an old version of NodeJS, or

b. you upgraded NodeJS, while you have Cypress code that is directly or indirectly incompatible (this could be your own code, or one of its dependencies) with that NodeJS version

Since SIGSEGV is a complete shutdown, you have no stack trace or debug information to guide you. So you have to debug the old fashioned way, turning tests and/or dependencies on or off to locate the problem in your code.